# How to make url in jQuery using query parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/tombonner/jurlp.

I want to make url using parameter. Can we make using this plugin?

Here is my code

```
// first case
var a = 'http://abc/deappsl/index.html?word=abc';
var abc = {
  test:"lo"
}

// second case
var a = 'http://abc/deappsl/index.html';
var abc = {
  test:"lo",
  p:'er'
}

// expected output
//first
//http://abc/deappsl/index.html?word=abc&test=lo

//second
//http://abc/deappsl/index.html?test=lo&p=er
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IEnUPyGAgCCCPeII0xh3?p=preview

I have two cases

- First In url I have already "?" and add param it give expected result using "&"
- second if url does not contain "?" then it add param with "?" and "&"

Can we use this plugin to make url?

Any update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the original URL using `$.jurlp`

```
var url = $.jurlp(a);
```

Then you can update the query parameters with the `.query()` method.

```
url.query(abc);
```

Then see the new URL

```
console.log(url.href);
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1HKFMQzGVWJVXxV0h2Y?p=preview)

Comment: please share plunker

Comment: it is not working please check http://plnkr.co/edit/IEnUPyGAgCCCPeII0xh3?p=preview

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. The documentation says **URL objects that have been returned via the parser interface can easily be converted to a string by calling the objects toString() method.**

Comment: Found it, use `url.href` to get the full URL string.